# How to set recognized content/MIME types for Spring Boot/MVC resources?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, undertow

Using [Spring MVC's ResourceHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) it's easy to serve resources.

However, some files, i.e. `.ico` files are not recognized properly, they don't get the proper `Content-Type` header. It seems that this is handled by `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` :

```
protected MediaType getMediaType(Resource resource) {
    MediaType mediaType = null;
    String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFilename());
    if (StringUtils.hasText(mimeType)) {
        mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(mimeType);
    }
    if (jafPresent && (mediaType == null || MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.equals(mediaType))) {
        MediaType jafMediaType = ActivationMediaTypeFactory.getMediaType(resource.getFilename());
        if (jafMediaType != null && !MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.equals(jafMediaType)) {
            mediaType = jafMediaType;
        }
    }
    return mediaType;
}
```

So how do I configure recognized file extensions / MIME types in Spring Boot 1.2? (for both Tomcat and Undertow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CustomizableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` has a [method for setting mime types](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.java#L114). You can get a callback by providing a bean of type `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`.

Comment: However this does not work when the application is deployed as a `war` in a separate servlet container. You should then configure the container, but I'm trying to come up with a solution that does not require configuring all  the server instances. Any ideas on how to handle this just in Spring Boot?

Comment: It's probably something you can configure in the container (e.g. Tomcat has a web.xml that creates default mappings for all apps).